# One on one chat with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have this type of query and I want to convert it to Laravel eloquent query without having to do a row query or `DB::select`.
This is how the row query looks like

```
Where (user_id = '$from' OR to = '$from') AND (user_id = '$to' OR to = '$to')
```

How do I do this in eloquent? So far I've just done

```
return $query->where('user_id', $from)->orWhere('to', $from)->get();
```

The intention is to get the conversation between two users without getting other users chats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
return $query->where(function($q) use ($from) {
        $q->where('user_id', $from)
          ->orWhere('to', $from);
    })->where(function ($q) use ($to) {
        $q->where('user_id', $to)
          ->orWhere(to, $to);
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Laerte

I found a better way and cleaner from ur code

```
return $query->where(['user_id' => $from, 'to' => $from])->orWhere(['user_id' => $to, 'to' => $to])->get();
```

Comment: Ok! Very nice! But did you check if this has the behavior you are looking? It seems to be working with "OR" and "AND" switched

Comment: Wow!!! You are so so right mate. I dint consider that. We need guys like you 

Comment: I'm glad to help :)